On VS Code, how can I create sections/bookmark specific lines in a Stata do-file?
I am writing a dofile (Stata script) on VS Code, and since it's pretty long, I would like to divide it into different sections so that I can easily navigate the script and quickly get to the lines I am interested in. Ideally, I would want these subsections to appear in the outline panel of VS Code. Alternatively, is there a way to make the Stata bookmarks **# work on VS Code as well?

I'd see if StataCorp Technical Support have any comment on this.

Thanks Nick! They told me that an extension would have to be
written for VS Code that can parse our bookmark comments and somehow list them in the outline panel. Unfortunately I do not know how to do that, but I will leave it here in case someone is interested

Not surprised to hear that, but sorry I know nothing about VS Code and can't help.
